# How to get color/depth Image data in unity with tango sdk

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

Is there a way to get the color/depth image data in unity? I've tried the AR example of tango, but the color image can't be seen. Can anyone share the experience? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about displaying Point Cluod then you should select "Tango Point Cloud" game object in the scene, make "MeshRenderer" component active and checkbox "Update pointcloud" has to be checked too. It will make point cloud visible.

Run your project, make a few taps on a screen and you will see that point cloud is updating when placing markers. To make point cloud updating constantly comment this line in ARGUIController.cs:

```
m_tangoApplication.SetDepthCameraRate(TangoEnums.TangoDepthCameraRate.DISABLED);
```